# What is this bolt/set of holes?

Tags: chevrolet, part-identification, drivetrain, suburban

[image: skid plate featuring two holes and a boly]
This skid plate(?) is underneath the transfer case (I think - about halfway back from the transmission, between the transmission and the differential) my 1997 Chevy Suburban K1500

Due to my brake related questions, I've been under the vehicle a lot and just noticed the bolt hanging out from the bottom of this skid plate.

Are these just drainage holes? Or did this bolt have a friend and a mount to go with it? I haven't closely inspected around it for a hole that's in need of a bolt yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure those are just drainage holes. The easiest thing to do is to remove the skid plate (yes, that's what it is) from the transfer case (yes, that's what it's attached to) and see where the bolt came from. Obviously, it shouldn't just be hanging down there and it had to come from somewhere. At this point I'm not quite sure *where* it might have come from, but pulling the skid plate would allow you to see things better. You have to know the bolt had to come from *somewhere* within the reach of the skid plate, so directly above it. I'm thinking it might be from the transfer mount further back in the frame, but still above the plate itself. The plate looks as though there are only four bolts holding it in. Replacing it after removal shouldn't be a hard task.

Comment: Bolt could've just bounced off the road and onto the tray, also.  Never know!